# What is the function of stringstream in C++ programmng?

Tags: c++, stringstream

Pls I am new to programming. I just started with c++, I got to a point where stringstream was used. The stuff is kinda confusing me. Pls somebody should help me out.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 6):

As for your problem, do you know how to use `std::cout` to write output? Do you know how to use `std::cin` to read input? Then you know everything you need to use just about *any* stream, including [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) (and its [output-only](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) and [input-only](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) siblings).

The difference is that the strings streams are to write to (or read from) a *string* instead of the console or terminal.

For example, lets say you want to construct a string from some other texts and some numbers, then you can use `std::ostringstream`:

```
std::string my_name = "Joachim";
int my_age = 42;

std::ostringstream ostr;
ostr << "My name is " << my_name
     << " and my age is " << my_age;

std::string str = ostr.str();  // Get the string constructed above

std::cout << str << '\n';  // Outputs "My name is Joachim and my age is 42"
```

Input string streams are probably not used as often as output string streams, but can be used to parse input from files on a line-by-line basis, by reading a line from the input file stream into a `std::string`, then use the input string stream to extract data much like you would use e.g. `std::cin`.

Comment: @ObajajaCourageCojay, Joachim gave you an excellent answer, now you should mark his answer as the Accepted Answer, which will give him reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to  explanation by Joachim Pileborg, I would like to add few things

stringstream is the `typedef "basic_stringstream<char>"` internally .

```
typedef basic_stringstream<char> stringstream;
```

Stream class to operate on strings.

Objects of this class use a string buffer that contains a sequence of characters. This sequence of characters can be accessed directly as a string object, using member str.

Characters can be inserted and/or extracted from the stream using any operation allowed on both input and output streams.

.

There is public member function .

```
std::stringstream::stringstream
default (1) 
explicit stringstream (ios_base::openmode which = ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
initialization (2)  
explicit stringstream (const string& str,
                       ios_base::openmode which = ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
```

Example :

```
#include <string>       // std::string
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <sstream>      // std::stringstream

int main () {

  std::stringstream ss;

  ss << 100 << ' ' << 200;

  int foo,bar;
  ss >> foo >> bar;

  std::cout << "foo: " << foo << '\n';
  std::cout << "bar: " << bar << '\n';

  return 0;
}


Output:
foo: 100
bar: 200
```

To sum up , string streams are basically used to perform input/output operation on string (with hell lot of functionality provided by the "std" which otherwise is hard to program) .

Comment: Ok @ Sifferman. How do I mark it as the answer cos I am new here

Comment: use upward arrow to accept the answer and downward arrow to reject the answer .